# Firefox force mp3 download instead of opening music player

Tags: html

I have link with an mp3 file, I've tried the following solutions but they seemed to work only on Chrome and Safari (Haven't tested I.E.). I'm trying to get it working in FF.

```
<a href="whatever_link.mp3" download="true">Click to download </a>
```

& in .htaccess

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp3

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Any possible solution for making the mp3 download in Firefox instead of opening the player in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

When the server sends the .mp3 file remove the MIME type so that Firefox treats it as a generic file.